# hide() not working as I was hoping

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? The original idea is if you click on any object on the carousel, info will fadeIn() at the bottom. I'm trying to understand why isn't allmsgs.hide() not functioning at all while swapping that line to m1.hide() to hide singular info works. I was really hoping that allmsgs.hide() would work to make it a bit more user-error-proof.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    autoPlay: 20000, 

        items : 4,
        itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3],
        StopOnHover : true,
        lazyEffect : 5000,
        mouseDrag : true
    });

    $('#panel1').on('click',function(event){
    var pan1 = $('#panel1');
    var m1 = $('#message1');
    var allpans = $('.panels');
    var allmsgs = $('.messages');
    allmsgs.hide();
    if(pan1.hasClass('clicked')){
    allpans.css('background','#bebec5').removeClass('clicked');
        }   else{
            m1.fadeIn('slow');
            pan1.css('background','#aec6d7').addClass('clicked');
            }
    });

    $('#panel2').on('click',function(event){
    var pan2 = $('#panel2');
    var m2 = $('#message2');
    var allpans = $('.panels');
    var allmsgs = $('.messages');
    allmsgs.hide();
    if(pan2.hasClass('clicked')){
    allpans.css('background','#bebec5').removeClass('clicked');
        }   else{
            m2.fadeIn('slow');
            pan2.css('background','#aec6d7').addClass('clicked');
            }
    });

    $('#panel3').on('click',function(event){
    var pan3 = $('#panel3');
    var m3 = $('#message3');
    var allpans = $('.panels');
    var allmsgs = $('.messages');
    allmsgs.hide();
    if(pan3.hasClass('clicked')){
    allpans.css('background','#bebec5').removeClass('clicked');
        }   else{
            m3.fadeIn('slow');
            pan3.css('background','#aec6d7').addClass('clicked');
            }
    });

});
```

Comment: Does the element actually have the class `.messages` ?

Comment: yes

<div class="container fluid" class="messages" id="message1" hidden>

Comment: Could you possibly make a JSfiddle for us to mess with?

Comment: Please provide html code or JSfiddle as @ViperCode said.

Comment: You can't have class="" twice inside a div. Your html has to be `<div class="container fluid messages"  id="message1" hidden>` . And what is 'hidden'? A class? data-attribute?

Comment: Sorry bros, new at jfiddle. Will try to get it to run there a bit later. Oh wait, you can't dump both classes in there? Thanks for the tip. The 'hidden' btw is an attribute. Clicking on an object on the carousel ends up revealing them.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being retarded. Macsupport spotted that thing I didn't know and I was able to get it the way I wanted it to run by omitting the else if parts.

```
$('#panel1').on('click',function(event){
var pan1 = $('#panel1');
var m1 = $('#message1');
var allpans = $('.panels');
var allmsgs = $('.messages');
allmsgs.hide();
allpans.css('background','#bebec5');
m1.fadeIn('slow');
pan1.css('background','#aec6d7');
});
```

Thanks a bunch anyway.